# Сдвигающийся вниз элемент в выпадающем меню

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется меню на сайте, которое должно открываться при наведении и номер, который должен сдвигаться вниз, как на картинках. Я написал пример ниже, единственная проблема именно в сдвигающимся вниз числе. Как его сделать?

**открытое меню**

[image: открытое меню]

**закрытое меню**

[image: закрытое меню]

```css
.header1 {
  margin-left: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 5.2%;
  text-align: right;
}

.header1 nav ul {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #f3f2ed;
  font-family: BrownLight;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  text-align: right;
}

.header1 nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}

.header1 nav a {
  font-size: 170%;
  display: block;
  font-family: BrownLight;
  padding: 0 25px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.header1 nav li:hover a {
  background: tranparent;
  color: #000;
}

.header1 nav li ul {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  left: 0;
  width: 150%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.header1 nav li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header1 nav li ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}

.header1 nav li ul a:hover {}


/* Clearfix */

.cf:after,
.cf:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header1">
  <nav>
    <ul class="cf">

      <li><a class="dropdown" href="#"><u>album:</u></a>

        <li><a href="#" style="color: #272524;">Art Works</a>
          <li> <a href="#" style="color: #272524;">Plien Air</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" style="color: #272524;">Museum practise</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" style="color: #272524;">Life from classes</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" style="color: #272524;">Shooting footage</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" style="color: #272524;">Sculpture classes</a></li>
          <li><a>03/14</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно понял?

Учтите, высота "выпадающего списка" фиксированная.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: inherit;
}

nav .placeholder,
nav .buttom {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav .placeholder {}

nav .buttom {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

nav>ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

nav>ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '..';
}

nav:hover>ul {
  height: calc(25px * 6); /* Высота li умножить на кол-во li */
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <a class="dropdown" href="#">album:</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="cf">
      <li><a href="#">Art Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Plien Air</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Museum practise</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Life from classes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shooting footage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sculpture classes</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="buttom">
      <a>03/14</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```